# apply a function to a subset of a data frame but retain the whole data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame and a vector identifying the rows I'm interested in:

```
col1 <- c("June","June","June 11","June 11, 2012","June 14, 2012")
col2 <- c("September", "September", "October 8", "October", "Sept 27, 2012")
monthDF <- data.frame(cbind(col1, col2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
v0 <- c(1, 2)
```

I also have two character vectors I would like to apply to the subset and specific columns.

```
startMonthV <- paste(c(" 1, ", substr(Sys.Date(), 1, 4)), collapse = "")
endMonthV <- paste(c(" 28, ", substr(Sys.Date(), 1, 4)), collapse = "")
```

I've tried using variations of the `apply()` function with `paste()` being the function I want to use, but to no avail. I would like my final result to be a data frame with all of the rows, but looking like this - the first two rows have been modified with the above startMonthV and endMonthV:

```
           col1                 col2
1  June 1, 2016   September 28, 2016
2  June 1, 2016   September 28, 2016
3       June 11            October 8
4 June 11, 2012              October
5 June 14, 2012        Sept 27, 2012
```

I'm new to R, and was wondering if the `apply()` family would do, or using a function within the plyr package. Any stackoverflow answer I've found either applies to the whole data frame or collapses the data with the `aggregate()` function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` and assign the result back at the corresponding rows:

```
days <- c("1,", "28,")
monthDF[v0, ] <- mapply(paste, monthDF[v0, ], days, substr(Sys.Date(), 1, 4))
monthDF
           col1               col2
1  June 1, 2016 September 28, 2016
2  June 1, 2016 September 28, 2016
3       June 11          October 8
4 June 11, 2012            October
5 June 14, 2012      Sept 27, 2012
```

Here we created a vector `days` according to the specific days you would like to append to the columns.

Comment: I may have simplified my example a little too much. I have other columns in the data frame before these two. I'll try modifying your solution to see if I can get to my desired solution.

Comment: `monthDF[v0, c("col1", "col2")] <- mapply(paste, monthDF[v0, c("col1", "col2")], days, substr(Sys.Date(), 1, 4))` should work.

Comment: was just about to post something similar but was two lines of code, addressing 1 column at a time. But, I like yours better. Again, thank you!